# How can I use multiple countdown with foreach loop in PHP? (I'm Beginner)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to print the countdowns in the database with a loop. I share the countdown codes and my table information in my database with you. Can you help me?

```js
<script>
  
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Sistem saatini alıyoruz
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Geri sayımla şimdi saat arasındaki zamanı ölçüyoruz
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    
    // Gün, Saat, Dakika, Saniye işlemleri yapılıyor
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Anlık olarak id="gerisayim" içine aktarılıyor
    document.getElementById().innerHTML = "Time ►" + days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds;
    
    // Süre dolduğunda yazacak yazı.
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);

        document.getElementById().innerHTML = "Started !";

        
        
        var bitistarihi = new Date().getTime();
        var y = setInterval(function() {
            var simdi = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = bitistarihi - simdi;
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById().innerHTML = "Time ►" + days + ": " + hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds;
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(y);

                document.getElementById().innerHTML = "Finish !";
                
                }
        }, 1000);

    }
}, 1000);


</script>
```

```html
<p>Test Countdown</p>

<div id=""></div>
```

The sample table in my database is as follows;

```
id tarih 
 1 2020-05-02 00:00:00
 2 2020-06-12 00:00:00
 3 2020-05-15 00:00:00
```

The id value in the table is the auto_increment primary key. The date (tarih) is datetime.

Comment: Where's your attempt? There is no PHP code in your question

Answer (score 0):

You should get data from database and sent to js code

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "DB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT tarih FROM countdown LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $countDownDate = $row["tarih"];
        }
    } else {
        $countDownDate = time();
    }

    $conn->close();
?>

<script>

    var countDownDate = '<?= $countDownDate ?>';
    //your code
    //...

</script>
```